# Powering multiple full-size bulbs

Tags: gpio, power, alternative-power

I'm working on a Pi project where I will need to have 4 lightbulb turn off and on based on schedule. The programming aspect is no problem but I'm guessing the GPIO pins are not powerful enough to do this. Assuming I need some sort of power controller that can hook up to the pins? Asking here because Google searches are yielding unhelpful info about the Pi power supply.

Comment: The GPIO can source max 16mA, default 8mA. What power, voltage are you trying to control.

Comment: @Milliways It looks like a 40-70 watt bulb draws ~500mA. We have 4 of them and, in theory, they could all be on at once.

Comment: Your comment did not answer the question I asked. If you want help on this site you should give sufficient information, and not have people guess. It seems that you are planning to use 110v AC lamps. The device suggested by timbotinkerer would seem to be suitable; it includes isolation and should be able to be driven by the Pi. There are more important safety considerations in controlling mains power.

Answer (score 1):

Hooking up the Pi pins to relays is the normal approach. 
You will need a separate power source for the lights.

I bought one of these for a similar purpose: http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=190950013824&ssPageName=ADME:L:OC:GB:3160